# How to add multiple words to an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, append

Thanks for all the suggestions It's really helped and I have made appropriate adjustments. Now there is just one last problem, when I enter the words to appear in the array, they actually appear in the array as individual letters. For Example if the word input was **football** in the array it appears as '**f**' '**o**' '**o**' '**t**' '**b**' '**a**' '**l**' '**l**'. And so when instead of a word chosen at random a letter is selected.

This segment of my code is taken from a hangman game

```
import random


SIX_NATIONS = ["WALES", "SCOTLAND", "ENGLAND", "FRANCE", "ITALY", "IRELAND"]

New_Topic = []

New_Topic_Choice = raw_input("Would you like to create your own topic? yes/no")

if New_Topic_Choice == "yes":

    Topic_Name = raw_input("What would you like the topic name to be: ")
    Topic_Words = raw_input("Enter all the words that you would like to appear in the array: ")
    str.split(Topic_Words)
    New_Topic.extend(Topic_Words)
    Word = random.choice(New_Topic)


else:
    Word = random.choice(SIX_NATIONS)
```

Thanks in advance for any replies.

P.S This version of Python is 2.7

Comment: Note that that's a `list` object; Python has an [`array` type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) too but you shouldn't confuse the two.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the function you are looking for is `list.extend()` rather than `list.append()`  extend, rather than append adds the elements of another list to a list rather than appending the list itself to the original list

As one of the other answers states, in order to split the string obtained from `raw_input()` you will have to use the `split()` functions which takes a string as an argument that is used as a separator (Which you must likely would like to be a space character) to create a list of strings.

Python Documentation:

1. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html
2. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: You'll have to teach the OP how to take multiple words from `raw_input()` too; at the moment all the OP has is one string..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you, I made the appropriate changes

Comment: Thanks. This is the edited code but I am still experiencing the same problem
                                                                       split_words = str.split("Enter all the words that you would like to appear in the array: ")
    New_Topic.extend(split_words)
    Word = random.choice(New_Topic)

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `New_Topic_Words` is a raw input, which is typically a string in python. The result when you add this string to your list `New_Topic`, is a list with only one element, the raw string.

If you want to add each word of the raw string, you need to split the raw string : `split_words = New_Topic_Words.split(' ')` and then use `New_Topic.extend(split_words)` to add each word as an list element.

You were using `append` which adds only one element, therefore adding a list as the last element. What you need is `extend` which concatenate two lists.

Comment: Thanks for that but even with 'extend' the error message states that "there is no attribute to extend"

Comment: @user3552372 Could you show us your code that gives you this error?

Comment: @PythonSpoilsYou, The line in which I said New_Topic.append(New_Topic_Words). With trying both 'append' and 'extend' the Python error message says: " 'str' object has no attribute 'append'/'extend' "

Comment: This means you are calling .append and .extend on a string object, instead of a list. New_Topic is first declared as a list with `[]` but then you affect a string, with a raw_input.

Comment: @LucasS. Oh okay, so to fix it would I need to replace 'raw_input'?

Comment: As you wish, maybe use an other variable to store the list, or an other variable to store the result of yout raw_input. Try to keep your code clear, variable names as well. Do not use variables twice for different purposes.